# Program returns message box again and again if 'no' is pressed in message box?

Tags: vba, excel, vlookup

The functon of program is to return the result of vlookup in the same cell in which the value to be looked up but it has two problems.

**1. It returns message box again and again if 'no' is pressed in message box?**

**2. I don't want message box to appear if enter is pressed on blank cells?**

here is the code

```
 Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim Ret_type As Integer
  Dim strMsg As String
  Dim strTitle As String
  If Target.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A114")) Is Nothing Then
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     Table2 = Sheet2.Range("C2:D3")
     strTitle = "Alert"
     strMsg = "Combination not found press Yes for manual entry"

     On Error Resume Next
        Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Table2, 2, False)
         Application.EnableEvents = True
         If Err.Number <> 0 Then
           Ret_type = MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo, strTitle)
              Select Case Ret_type
               Case 7
                ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Clear
              End Select
         End If
         On Error GoTo 0 ''no error, coming back to default conditions 
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1: Make sure to only re-enable events AFTER every change has been made by the code. Otherwise it will keep relaunching itself in a recursion.

2: Check at the beginning of the code if target is empty.

+1: Don't use activecell.offset in macros like this; your user could have clicked any cell, and in that case, offset makes no sense. Use the Target variable instead.

Your code was pretty chaotic, and I'm not sure it makes total sense at this point. Anyway, here is a working version. See my in-line comments for points of interest.

I also have simplified it a bit, removing a few useless structures.

```
 Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

  Dim strMsg As String
  Dim strTitle As String

  If Target.Cells.Count > 1 Then Exit Sub
  If Target.Value = "" Then Exit Sub 'don't bother with a blank cell

  If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A1:A114")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Table2 = Sheet2.Range("C2:D3")
    strTitle = "Alert"
    strMsg = "Combination not found press Yes for manual entry"

    On Error Resume Next
      Target.Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Target.Value, Table2, 2, False)
      If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        If MsgBox(strMsg, vbYesNo, strTitle) = vbYes Then
          Target.Clear 'Better than the offset version; this works also if your user uses tab or mouse click, not only enter
        End If
      End If
    On Error GoTo 0
    Application.EnableEvents = True 'only re-enable events AFTER having changed everything you want to change
  End If
End Sub
```